# How do I get a value out of a group?

Tags: programming, latex3, grouping, expl3

I've just recovered from my first real foray into LaTeX3 programming.  It was ... an experience.  Not a completely unpleasant one and once I'd gotten used to the syntax then I found it a lot easier than it looks.  I almost was able to forget that I was programming in a macro language and start thinking in terms of functions and variables again.

Almost.

Where I came up against a brick wall was in the concept of auxiliary functions.  I had a main function that did a lot of work.  I would quite like to have farmed off parts of it to some other functions, as much for keeping track of what was going on as anything else.  But I couldn't work out how to do that separation properly.

Here's an example.  Suppose I wanted to compute the Euclidean length of a lot of 2-vectors.  In, say, lua then I might write:

```
function veclen(a,b)
  return math.sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
end
```

Now that isn't directly comparable with a LaTeX3 "function" so let me pretend that I can't write inline formulae in lua and write it out a bit more like LaTeX3.

```
function veclen(a,b)
  local s = a
  local t = b
  multiply(s,s)
  multiply(t,t)
  add(s,t)
  sqrt(s)
  return s
end
```

Here, `multiply` and `add` are functions that "do what they say on the tin" but, crucially, instead of returning a value they store the answer in the first variable.

That's fairly similar to my LaTeX3 function:

```
\cs_new:Nn \fp_veclen:NNN {
  \fp_set_eq:NN \l_hobby_veclena_fp #2
  \fp_set_eq:NN \l_hobby_veclenb_fp #3
  \fp_mul:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {\l_hobby_veclena_fp}
  \fp_mul:Nn \l_hobby_veclenb_fp {\l_hobby_veclenb_fp}
  \fp_add:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {\l_hobby_veclenb_fp}
  \fp_pow:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {.5}
  \fp_set_eq:NN #1 \l_hobby_veclena_fp
}
```

The crucial difference, and what I'm asking about, is the scoping.

In the lua function, `a` and `b` are local but even if they are not then the commands `local s = a` and `local t = b` force them to be local.  But the `return s` breaks out of the function scope and makes the answer available at the next level up.  In doing this in TeX, I'd do all my computations inside a group: something like:

```
\cs_new:Nn \fp_veclen:NNN {
\group_begin:
  \fp_set_eq:NN \l_hobby_veclena_fp #2
  \fp_set_eq:NN \l_hobby_veclenb_fp #3
  \fp_mul:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {\l_hobby_veclena_fp}
  \fp_mul:Nn \l_hobby_veclenb_fp {\l_hobby_veclenb_fp}
  \fp_add:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {\l_hobby_veclenb_fp}
  \fp_pow:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {.5}
\group_end:
\fp_set_eq:NN #1 \l_hobby_veclena_fp
}
```

Except that that wouldn't work: if I put the `\group_end:` where I have done so then `\l_hobby_veclena_fp` has lost its value.  If I put it *after* the assignment then the assignment is local to the group and so is lost moments later.

To cut a long story short: I want the *computation* to be local so that I can use my temporary variables with impunity, but I need the *assignment* to be outside the computation group (but *not* global) so that it can be used by the calling code.

How do I do this?  Obviously it is possible because the LaTeX3 functions must do this all the time[1].  TikZ uses "smuggling" to do this: define a temporary global variable to be the answer and then outside the group make the assignment which makes the actual assignment not global but outside the computation group: `\global\let\tikz@smuggle=\the@answer\endgroup\let\the@answer=\tikz@smuggle`.  What's the right LaTeX3-way to do this?

For bonus points, there's another small issue with scoping.  In the lua function, the variables `a` and `b` were already local: I could reassign them with impunity.  In TeX, that's not so easy.  If I do something like

```
\fp_set_eq:NN \l_my_tmpa_fp #1
\fp_set_eq:NN \l_my_tmpb_fp #2
```

then there's always the danger that I called my function with `\calc:NN \l_my_tmpb_fp \l_my_tmpa_fp`.  How do I make local aliases for my incoming variables *without* defining a new set of temporary macros for every single function?

[1] I know I could look at the LaTeX3 code - indeed I took a quick glance and got a vague idea, but I suspect that there would be subtleties I'd miss by not asking, and I hope that others will benefit from a more public answer and explanation.

Comment: You can use `\fp_gset_eq:NN #1 \l_hobby_veclena_fp` inside the group.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel But that *globally* sets whatever-#1-was to `\l_hobby_veclena_fp`.  But `#1` was (or could have been) only a local variable in the calling function.  So it might have another global value that I don't want to touch.

Comment: Why not use the TikZ way? Seems nice'n'easy to me...

Comment: @cgnieder: I believe in the separation of TikZ and LaTeX3.  Seriously, if there's a "proper l3 way" to do this, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: You can use: `\edef\@tempa{\endgroup\value=\the\value\relax}\@tempa` to move a value (counter, length) out of a group. Don't ask me how to translated that into Klingon, aeh, LaTeX3. The same is possible for macros: `\edef\@tempa{\endgroup\def\noexpand\mymacro{\mymacro}}\@tempa` or, if you don't want to expand it all the way: `\def\@tempa{\endgroup\def\noexpand\mymacro{\unexpanded\expandafter{\mymacro}}}\@tempa`, or without e-TeX: `\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter\mymacro\expandafter{\mymacro}`. The first two values also work nicely with multiple macros/registers.

Comment: @AndrewStacey to avoid problems when tmpa or tmpb are given as arguments to your functions, you could use `\fp_veclen:Nxx` instead of `\fp_veclen:NNN`, coded as `\cs_new_protected \fp_veclen:Nnn #1#2#3 { \group_begin: \fp_set:Nn \..._tmpa_fp {#2} ... \group_end: }` and `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_veclen:Nnn { Nxx }`.  With the upcoming fp module (some time in June/July), you'll be able to do `\cs_new_protected:Npn \fp_veclen:Nnn #1#2#3 { \fp_set:Nn #1 { ((#2)^2 + (#3)^2)^.5 } }` directly, avoiding all issues.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Thanks for the tip.  There's lots I'm learning about LaTeX3 and having experts like you and Joseph (and others) around definitely helps.  I'm looking forward to the fp module - would make a lot of the code *much* simpler.

Comment: I'm accepting Will's answer as it's the one I'm using.  I'd like to say that all the answers (and comments) taught me something so many thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Soln 1

This might be considered overkill, but I once wrote a function `\group_after_set:NNn` to provide an "abstraction" to handle this, used as in:

```
\group_begin:
  \group_begin:
    \group_after_set:NNn \int_set:Nn \y {3}
    % \y == 3
  \group_end:
  % \y == 3
\group_end:
% \y == undefined
```

I quite like it but I don't know if should be added to expl3 or not. Suggestions?

The advantage over this approach is that you can use it multiple times within a group to "export" multiple variables, unlike Enrico's answer which is much more simple and efficient for the common case.

Anyway, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_if_free:NT \group_insert_after:N
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \group_insert_after:N \group_execute_after:N
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nT {v}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_show:N {v}
\cs_new:Nn \group_after_set:NNn
{
  % set the variable locally for use inside the group:
  #1 #2 {#3}

  \cs_if_exist:cF { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
    {
      \tl_new:c { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
    }

  % first time the function is executed inside the group:
  \tl_if_empty:vT { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
    {
      % set up the aftergroup execution:
      \group_insert_after:c
        { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }

      % reset the material for aftergroup execution:
      \tl_gset:cx { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
        {
          \tl_gclear:c { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
        }
    }

  % append the new material to the aftergroup execution:
  \tl_gput_right:cx
    { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
    {
      \exp_not:n { #1 #2 } { \exp_not:V #2 }
    }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \group_insert_after:N {c}

\int_new:N \y
\int_new:N \yy

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnF {V}
\cs_new:Nn \assert:Nn
  {
    \tl_if_eq:VnF #1 {#2} {[ERROR:\tl_to_str:n{#1~!=~#2}]}
  }

\group_begin:
  \group_after_set:NNn \tl_set:Nn \x {xx}
  \group_after_set:NNn \tl_set:Nn \xx {x}
  \assert:Nn \x {xx}
  \assert:Nn \xx {x}
  \group_begin:
    \group_after_set:NNn \int_set:Nn \y {3}
    \group_after_set:NNn \int_set:Nn \yy {2}
    \assert:Nn \y  {3}
    \assert:Nn \yy {2}
  \group_end:
  \assert:Nn \x {xx}
  \assert:Nn \xx {x}
  \assert:Nn \y  {3}
  \assert:Nn \yy {2}

  % check repeated doesn't break anything:
  \group_begin:
    \int_set:Nn \y  {6}
    \int_set:Nn \yy {5}
  \group_end:
  \assert:Nn \x {xx}
  \assert:Nn \xx {x}
  \assert:Nn \y  {3}
  \assert:Nn \yy {2}
\group_end:

\assert:Nn \x {xx}
\assert:Nn \xx {x}
\assert:Nn \y  {0}
\assert:Nn \yy {0}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Edit: add some comments and clean up the code slightly.

## Soln 2 (added later)

From some discussion elsewhere on this page with Ahmed, it's become clear to me that the syntax introduced about isn't such a great idea. For example, if you want to set a variable using `tl_set:Nx`, it's not then appropriate to use that same function to define the variable outside the group. Really what we're looking for is an extension of etextool's `\AfterGroup` that permits easy expansion control (which is part of the whole design philosophy of expl3).

So separating the local and "group escaped" variables need to be done independently, syntax-wise. Here's a modified implementation of the above that does this. The code looks similar:

```
\int_new:N \y
\group_begin:
  \group_begin:
    \int_set:Nn \y {3}
    \group_var_return:NN \int_set:Nn \y
    % \y == 3
  \group_end:
  % \y == 3
\group_end:
% \y == 0
```

Note that since we don't have a mapping between variable types and their setting functions, in this case `\int_set:Nn` is required twice. This isn't so bad, really, since you could in theory use this for all sorts of setting functions. So the "general" approach here I've written as follows:

```
\clist_new:N \z
% ...

\group_begin:
  % let's say we're in a macro right now that processes
  % some input argument and saves the result to "\y".
  \do_something_with:Nn \y {#1}
  \group_after_insert:nV { \clist_put_right:Nn \z } { \y }
\group_end:
```

So it's easy to see how the former (`\group_var_return:NN`) is just something like `\group_after_insert:nV { \int_set:Nn \y } \y`. Whether these levels of abstraction are necessary or helpful is a bit of an open question. I'm inclined to think that at least the `\group_var_return:NN` one looks good.

Here is the implementation of all that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_if_free:NT \group_insert_after:N
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \group_insert_after:N \group_execute_after:N
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nT {v}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \group_insert_after:N {c}

\cs_new:Nn \group_after_insert:nn
{ 
  \cs_if_exist:cF { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
    {
      \tl_new:c { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
    }

  % first time the function is executed inside the group:
  \tl_if_empty:vT { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
    {
      % set up the aftergroup execution:
      \group_insert_after:c
        { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }

      % reset the material for aftergroup execution:
      \tl_gset:cx { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
        {
          \tl_gclear:c { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
        }
    }

  % append the new material to the aftergroup execution:
  \tl_gput_right:cx
    { g_aftergroup_ \int_use:N \etex_currentgrouplevel:D _tl }
    {
      \exp_not:n { #1 {#2} }
    }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \group_after_insert:nn {nV}

\cs_new:Npn \group_var_return:NN #1 #2
{
  \group_after_insert:nV { #1 #2  } { #2 } 
}

\int_new:N \y
\int_new:N \yy

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnF {V}
\cs_new:Nn \assert:Nn
  {
    \tl_if_eq:VnF #1 {#2} {[ERROR:\tl_to_str:n{#1~!=~#2}]}
  }

\group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \x {xx}
  \tl_set:Nn \xx {x}
  \group_after_insert:nV { \tl_set:Nn \x  } { \x  }
  \group_after_insert:nV { \tl_set:Nn \xx } { \xx }
  \assert:Nn \x {xx}
  \assert:Nn \xx {x}
  \group_begin:
    \int_set:Nn \y {3}
    \int_set:Nn \yy {2}
    \group_var_return:NN \int_set:Nn \y
    \group_var_return:NN \int_set:Nn \yy
    \assert:Nn \y  {3}
    \assert:Nn \yy {2}
  \group_end:
  \assert:Nn \x {xx}
  \assert:Nn \xx {x}
  \assert:Nn \y  {3}
  \assert:Nn \yy {2}

  % check repeated doesn't break anything:
  \group_begin:
    \int_set:Nn \y  {6}
    \int_set:Nn \yy {5}
  \group_end:
  \assert:Nn \x {xx}
  \assert:Nn \xx {x}
  \assert:Nn \y  {3}
  \assert:Nn \yy {2}
\group_end:

\assert:Nn \x {xx}
\assert:Nn \xx {x}
\assert:Nn \y  {0}
\assert:Nn \yy {0}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: I vote for implementation ;-)

Comment: Obviously `\group_after_set:Nn` isn't the best name for the thing, though.

Comment: Gets my vote, and floats my boat, and doesn't get my goat (I'll get my coat).

Comment: @WillRobertson: If this is all about eTeX's `\currentgrouptype`, please have you simply used the returned number (0,16)? I am sorry, I don't do LaTeX3 at all; I am sure you know that. In the past I have had trouble getting out of deep groups (for error recovery) using `\currentgrouptype`. I can ask a separate question if that will help.

Comment: @AhmedMusa — I'm not sure I exactly understand the question. All this code uses, really, is `\aftergroup` and `\currentgrouplevel`; the latter is used to keep track of which level of nesting we're in because the token passed to `\aftergroup` has to be global. But I haven't nested it extensively; there is a chance there are deep/edge cases I'm not aware of.

Comment: I *like* `\group_var_return:NN`.  Consider it stolen^H^H^H^H^H^Hcopied.

Answer (score 12):

With the new FPU, we can avoid the group entirely in this particular case (for the more general 'escape from a group' question, see the [answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56314)).

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \fp_veclen:NNN #1#2#3
 {
   \fp_set:Nn #1
     {
        ( ( #2 ) ^ 2 + ( #3 ) ^ 2 ) ^ ( 0.5 )
     }
 }
```

(At the time of writing, this needs the development version of `expl3` rather than the CTAN release.)

On the 'bonus' part to the question, I'd simply pass the values using `V`-type expansion. TeX grouping does not work like Lua grouping, so you can't group in the way you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the `V`.  And I've missed not being able to use expressions for `fp` stuff so I'm looking forward to that being in the official version.

Answer (score 11):

You simply have to get the value of the variable before closing the group; since you have to skip three tokens, `\exp_args:NNNV` is what you need:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \fp_veclen:NNN #1 #2 #3
 {
  \group_begin:
  \fp_set_eq:NN \l_hobby_veclena_fp #2
  \fp_set_eq:NN \l_hobby_veclenb_fp #3
  \fp_mul:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {\l_hobby_veclena_fp}
  \fp_mul:Nn \l_hobby_veclenb_fp {\l_hobby_veclenb_fp}
  \fp_add:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {\l_hobby_veclenb_fp}
  \fp_pow:Nn \l_hobby_veclena_fp {.5}
  \exp_args:NNNV \group_end: \fp_set:Nn #1 \l_hobby_veclena_fp
 }
```

As Joseph remarks in a comment this should be `protected`, being not expandable; the `Npn` variety is more efficient.

If more variables have to be set outside the group, a different method must be used (waiting for Will's proposal to be implemented); the last line in the definition can become

```
\use:x
 {
  \group:end
  \fp_set:Nn \exp_not:N #1 { \l_hobby_veclena_fp }
  % other similar assignments
 }
```

(Thanks to Joseph Wright and Marco Daniel for remarking it.)

Note that `\fp_veclen:Nnn` should have this signature if you plan to call it as `\fp_veclen:Nnn \l_hobby_veclen_fp {2}{3}`. Also `\fp_set_eq:NN` should be `\fp_set:Nn`.

Comment: This should be `\cs_new_protected` as it's not expandable; I'd also favour `\cs_new_protected:Npn`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I've added the remark; as I wrote, this can be particularly useful when more than one assignment has to be performed "outside the group".

Answer (score 1):

Will Robertson has sent me an eTeX translation of this LaTeX3 solution, which I have adapted substantially. The difference between Will's and Martin Scharrer's solutions is that Martin's scheme deals with only one type of group (semi simple group). See also **etextools**'s `\AfterGroup`, which works for all groups but doesn't accumulate code as Will's scheme does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
% The star (*) variant executes code #1 within the group. #1 must be 
% executable in this case. The un-starred version simply takes the 
% material outside the group.
\robust@def*\aftergroupexecute{\cpt@testst\cpt@aftergroupexecute}
\robust@def\cpt@aftergroupexecute#1{%
  \ifboolTF{cpt@st}{#1}{}%
  % \ag@elt is local to current group:
  \def\ag@elt{aftergroup@execute@\romannumeral\currentgrouplevel}%
  \ifcsndefTF\ag@elt{}{%
    \aftercsname\aftergroup\ag@elt
    % for post \aftergroup resetting:
    \csn@xdef\ag@elt{\gundefcsn{\ag@elt}}%
  }%
  \csn@xdef\ag@elt{\expandcsnonce\ag@elt\unexpanded{#1}}%
}    
\makeatother
% Tests
\begin{document}
\def\x{FOO}
\def\y{ZOO}
\begingroup
  \begingroup
    \hbox{%
      \vbox to 5cm{%
        $
          \aftergroupexecute{\def\x{foo}}%
          \aftergroupexecute{\def\y{zoo}}%
        $
        %\show\x
        \show\y
      }%
      \show\x
    }%
    \show\x
  \endgroup
  \show\x
\endgroup
\show\x
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Will, Please how will your scheme work in the following scenario? This isn't a debate; my aim is to understand your scheme. I want only `\includelater` and `\somemasters` outside the adjusted hbox group.

```
\hbox{%
  \def\classlist{David/Salomon, Michael/Downes, Frank/Mittelbach, David/Carlisle, 
    David/Kastrup, Heiko/Oberdiek, Till/Tantau, Donald/Arseneau, Joseph/Wright, 
    Hans/Hagen, Taco/Hoekwater, Hartmut/Henkel, Robin/Fairbain, Ulrike/Fischer, 
    Ulrich/Diez}
  % Let Will's processing function be \do:
  \def\do#1/#2,{%
    \ifx\do#1\else
      \noexpand\elt{\cpttrimspace{#1}}{\cpttrimspace{#2}}%
      \expandafter\do
    \fi
  }%
  \edef\classlist{\expandafter\do\classlist,\do/,}%
  \aftergroupexecute{\def\includelater{Will Robertson}}
  \expandafter\aftergroupexecute\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter
  \somemasters\expandafter{\classlist}}
}
%\show\includelater
\show\somemasters
```

Comment: A disadvantage to this syntax IMO is that what is in `\aftergroupexecute` still needs to be expanded if you're passing out results of a calculation. E.g., `foo` must still consist of non-local material.

Comment: @WillRobertson: I am afraid I don't understand your comment. Perhaps you could send me an email. In the meantime, in the example given, with the *-variant you have the option of executing `\def\x{foo}` (or any given <code>) within the local group, or simply passing it on to outside the group. In your approach, you hardwired `\def#1{#2}`, implying that only the definition of `#1` could take place within and outside the group.

Comment: Let's say you want to take some input and process it using a scratch variable, then output it in `\x`. So you're writing something like `\begingroup \def\@tempa{#1} \processingfunction \y {«something with \@tempa»} \aftergroupexecute{ \def\x{\y} } \endgroup`. How do you get `\x` defined as `\y` without doing yet more ugly expansion control?

Comment: To be fair I don't think my syntax is perfect either. I now think it's better to separate local assignment and the declaration of "returning" a variable. So if I re-wrote my answer now I'd prefer a syntax like `\group_return_variable:N \x` where the local value of `\x` would remain after the group ended.

Comment: Well, I don't know LaTeX3, but `\begingroup\def\foo{foo}\aftergroup\foo\endgroup`, of course, won't work.

Comment: See my edit to my original answer for an expansion of some of this discussion including example code…

Answer (score 1):

Now with [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package (which is based on `expl3`) we can do programming in a way similar to `Lua` language. Note that `\Result` command collects the return value and passes it out of the function group.

```lua
-- lua code for comparison --
function veclen(a,b)
  return math.sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
end
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\Functional{scoping=true} % make every function become a group
\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \veclen { M M } {
  \Result { \FpEval { ( (#1)^2 + (#2)^2 ) ^ (0.5) } }
}
\FpSet \lTmpaFp {1.2}
\FpSet \lTmpbFp {3.4}
\veclen \lTmpaFp \lTmpbFp
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\end{document}
```

And changes to the local variables are reset out of the function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\Functional{scoping=true} % make every function become a group
\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \veclenx { M M } {
  \FpSet #1 {-1.2}
  \FpSet #2 {-3.4}
  \Result { \FpEval { ( (#1)^2 + (#2)^2 ) ^ (0.5) } }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\FpSet \lTmpaFp {1.2}
\FpSet \lTmpbFp {3.4}
\veclenx \lTmpaFp \lTmpbFp

\string\lTmpaFp{} = \FpUse \lTmpaFp,
\string\lTmpbFp{} = \FpUse \lTmpbFp.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of `\AfterGroup` that I think is easy to use and straight-forward:

```latex
\ProvideDocumentCommand \AfterGroup {ooom}%
{   \cs_set:Npn \l_tmpa_cs  ##1##2##3%
    {   \tl_set:Nn  \l_tmpa_tl  {#4}    }
    \exp_args:Neee  \l_tmpa_cs  {#1}{#2}{#3}
    \tl_map_inline:Nn   \l_tmpa_tl  {\group_insert_after:N##1}
}
```

You would pass the values needing expanding as optional arguments (up to three), and then the code to run using those arguments:

```
\group_begin:
\def\l_some_variable{stuff and such}
\def\l_other_stuff{ń̥o҉̙̻̖̲̮͓̩̀t̵̬̳͔ḩ̡̪͇͈i̼̦̮̙͝n̸̸̲̲͍̟g͏̭͖̠̩̭}
\AfterGroup[\l_some_variable][\l_other_stuff]{\Large #1~or~#2}
\group_end:
```