# Using \end in internal vertical mode

Tags: loops

Please how do I stop at all cost in the following? Note: `\leavevmode` is no rescue.

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\def\z#1#2{%
  \ifnum#1<\numexpr#2+1\relax
    \noindent\hfill#1%
    \ifnum#1=#2\relax
      \hfill\null\endgraf
    \else
      \ifdefined\xz
        \hfill\number\numexpr#1+1\hfill\null\endgraf
      \else
        \let\xz\relax\hfill\null\endgraf
      \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\z\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+2\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\z19
\stop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The output image you've attached appears to be produced only if `\documentclass{article}` is used, but not if `\documentclass[crop]{standalone}` is in effect. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you say a little more what you mean by "stop at all costs"?  It seems that the loop terminates, at least; do you mean you want to stop executing in the middle of the loop?

Comment: With the MWE as written, you get `! Missing } inserted.` as the error: replace the `crop` option by `preview` to get ``! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.``, which relates  more to the title.

Comment: @Mico: Joseph Wright has answered the question. I didn't look in *standalone.sty* to see the boxing that it does. Ditto Ryan Reich.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the standard settings, `standalone` class uses an `\hbox` to work. You can see this if you add

```
\showthe\currentgrouplevel
\showthe\currentgrouptype
```

before `\stop`: the reported values are group level 1 and group type 2 ('hbox group'). You simply cannot use the `\end` primitive inside a box and expect all to be well. Moreover, even if you test for a box using the e-TeX extensions, closing it does not help as the content then disappears as you get no output. So with a complex set up such as the `standalone` class you really do have to 'stick to the rules' in terms of interface, or write everything yourself.

Comment: Do you think the scheme at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56294/how-do-i-get-a-value-out-of-a-group/56681#56681 can help?

Comment: @AhmedMusa Possibly, but if there is more than once group level then life gets extremely complicated. In that case, you'll need to insert code which will then check again on the group type, and insert `\stop` only when you are 'safe'.