# How to define macros in a foreach loop with effects between iterations and after the loop without using global?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, programming, loops, foreach

Without using `\global`, the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etextools}

\newcommand\appendbyforeach[2]{%
  \AfterGroup*{\noexpand\AfterGroup{\noexpand\edef\noexpand#1{\noexpand#1#2}}}
}

\newcommand\defincbyforeach[2]{%
  \AfterGroup*{\noexpand\def\noexpand#1{#2}}
  \AfterGroup*{\noexpand\AfterGroup{\noexpand\def\noexpand#1{#2}}}
}

\newcommand\meaningwithname[1]{\textbackslash#1: \expandafter\meaning\csname #1\endcsname}

\newcommand\mymacro{
  \begingroup
  \def\myarray{init}
  \def\valmax{0}
  \foreach \i in {1,8,-3}{
    \appendbyforeach{\myarray}{,\i}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\max}{\valmax < \i ? \i : \valmax}
    \defincbyforeach\valmax{\max}
    %%% print state of \myarray and \valmax
    foreach \i\\\meaningwithname{myarray}\\\meaningwithname{valmax}\par
  }
  inside\\\meaningwithname{myarray}\\\meaningwithname{valmax}\par
  \endgroup
  outside\\\meaningwithname{myarray}\\\meaningwithname{valmax}\par
}

\begin{document}\mymacro\end{document}
```

produces a document containing:

```
    foreach 1
\myarray: macro:->init
\valmax: macro:->0
    foreach 8
\myarray: macro:->init
\valmax: macro:->1.0
    foreach -3
\myarray: macro:->init
\valmax: macro:->8.0
    inside
\myarray: macro:->init,1,8,-3
\valmax: macro:->8.0
    outside
\myarray: \relax
\valmax: \relax
```

This result suits me well!

But is there a better way to define macros `\appendbyforeach` and `\defincbyforeach` while achieving the same effects?

Does `etextools` package is really practical here?

Comment: I could just leave the question here and add my solution as an answer. Would it be better?

Comment: Is the problem finding the max of an array with a locally defined macro?

Comment: @percusse This is just one example of usage of `\defincbyforeach`. The idea is to calculate (for each iteration and after the loop), $u_n = f(u_ {n-1}, x_1, x_2, ...)$ where $x_1,x_2,...$ are the variables of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** This code always uses `etextools`. Before accepting my answer to my own question, I hope that others will offer me more interesting solutions (without `etextools`, more effective, faster, simpler...). But always without using `\global`!

**Edit:** Here a new version without expanded values and with only two macros.

1. `\afteriterationdef` to (re)define a macro after current iteration.
2. `\afterforeachdef` to (re)define a macro after foreach (and after iteration).

Here is the code of these two macros:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etextools}

\makeatletter

% define a macro after current iteration
\newcommand\afteriterationdef[1]{\aftergroup@def#1}

% define a macro after foreach (and after iteration)
\newcommand\afterforeachdef[1]{\afteriterationdef{#1}\AfterGroup{\aftergroup@def#1}}

\makeatother
```

And an example:

```
\newcommand\meaningwithname[1]{%
  \textbackslash#1: \expandafter\meaning\csname #1\endcsname}

\newcommand\mymacro{
  {
    \def\myarray{init}
    \def\myvalue{1}
    \foreach \i in {1,8,-3,-1}{
      % append some value to \myarray
      \edef\myarray{\myarray,\i}
      \afterforeachdef\myarray
      % incremental definition of \mtvalue
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myvalue}{\myvalue*\i}
      \afterforeachdef\myvalue
      %%% print meaning of \myarray and \myvalue at each iteration
      foreach \i: \meaningwithname{myarray}, \meaningwithname{myvalue}\par
    }
    %%% print meaning of \myarray and \myvalue after \foreach
    inside group: \meaningwithname{myarray}, \meaningwithname{myvalue}\par
  }
  %%% print meaning of \myarray and \myvalue outside
  outside group: \meaningwithname{myarray}, \meaningwithname{myvalue}\par
}

\begin{document}\mymacro\end{document}
```

This example produces this text:

```
foreach 1: \myarray: macro:->init,1, \myvalue: macro:->1.0
foreach 8: \myarray: macro:->init,1,8, \myvalue: macro:->8.0
foreach -3: \myarray: macro:->init,1,8,-3, \myvalue: macro:->-24.0
foreach -1: \myarray: macro:->init,1,8,-3,-1, \myvalue: macro:->24.0
inside group: \myarray: macro:->init,1,8,-3,-1, \myvalue: macro:->24.0
outside group: \myarray: \relax, \myvalue: \relax
```

**Edit 2:** Another example with two nested `\foreach`:

```
\newcommand\mymacrowithnestedforeach{
  {
    \def\myarray{init}
    \def\myvalue{1}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
      \foreach \j in {1,...,3}{
        % append some value to \myarray
        \edef\myarray{\myarray,(\i,\j)}
        \afterforeachdef\myarray
        % incremental definition of \myvalue
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myvalue}{\myvalue+\j*\i}
        \afterforeachdef\myvalue
        %%% print meaning of \myarray and \myvalue at each iteration
        int foreach \i: \meaningwithname{myarray}, \meaningwithname{myvalue}\par
      }
      % 
      \afterforeachdef\myarray
      \afterforeachdef\myvalue
      %%% print meaning of \myarray and \myvalue at each iteration
      ext foreach \i: \meaningwithname{myarray}, \meaningwithname{myvalue}\par
    }
    %%% print meaning of \myarray and \myvalue after \foreach
    inside  group: \meaningwithname{myarray}, \meaningwithname{myvalue}\par
  }
  %%% print meaning of \myarray and \myvalue outside
  outside group: \meaningwithname{myarray}, \meaningwithname{myvalue}\par
}

\begin{document}\mymacrowithnestedforeach\end{document}
```

This example produces this text:

```
int foreach 1: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1), \myvalue: macro:->2.0
int foreach 1: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2), \myvalue: macro:->4.0
int foreach 1: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3), \myvalue: macro:->7.0
ext foreach 1: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3), \myvalue: macro:->7.0
int foreach 2: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1), \myvalue: macro:->9.0
int foreach 2: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2), \myvalue: macro:->13.0
int foreach 2: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3), \myvalue: macro:->19.0
ext foreach 2: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3), \myvalue: macro:->19.0
int foreach 3: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1), \myvalue: macro:->22.0
int foreach 3: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2), \myvalue: macro:->28.0
int foreach 3: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3), \myvalue: macro:->37.0
ext foreach 3: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3), \myvalue: macro:->37.0
inside group: \myarray: macro:->init,(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3), \myvalue: macro:->37.0
outside group: \myarray: \relax, \myvalue: \relax
```

Comment: This will fail for nested groups and nested `\foreach`. See the discussion at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56294/how-do-i-get-a-value-out-of-a-group/56681#56681.

Comment: @AhmedMusa This solution works with nested `\foreach` (I added an example to my answer). If you define a macro into a group into a `\foreach`, you should first call `\aftergroup@def` into this group then call `\afterforeachdef` outside this group and into the `\foreach`.