# How to make global a color list definition with \@namedef done inside a foreach loop

Tags: macros, programming, foreach

#### Motivation

As stated in the title, I'm trying to define a command able, from a list of colors as input, to create a list in which colors are numbered. This, manually, has been done in  [Arrows coordinates in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52961/arrows-coordinates-in-tikz)

#### Preliminary work

I've tried to search in the site questions related to the problem, such as [How to define macros in a foreach loop with effects between iterations and after the loop without using global?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69470/how-to-define-macros-in-a-foreach-loop-with-effects-between-iterations-and-after),  [How to define macros in a foreach loop with effects between iterations and after the loop without using global?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69470/how-to-define-macros-in-a-foreach-loop-with-effects-between-iterations-and-after) (especially solutions shown in Martin's comment). But I can't figure out a solution when the definition is based on `\@namedef`

#### The minimal-non-working-example

This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\setcolorlist}[1]{
        \foreach \listitem [count=\i] in {#1}{
            \global\let\@tempa\@namedef{color@\i}{\listitem}
        }
        \@tempa
}

% Command in which colors are necessary
\newcommand{\drawcoloredarrows}[1]{
    \foreach \i  in {#1}{
        \edef\mycolor{\@nameuse{color@\i}}
        \draw[\mycolor,-stealth] (0,-\i)--(2,-\i); 
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcolorlist{red,cyan,blue,green}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawcoloredarrows{1,...,4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

getting:

[image]

#### How it should work

This is how it should work:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{color@1}{red}
\@namedef{color@2}{cyan}   
\@namedef{color@3}{blue} 
\@namedef{color@4}{green}  

\newcommand{\setcolorlist}[1]{
        \foreach \listitem [count=\i] in {#1}{
            \global\let\@tempa\@namedef{color@\i}{\listitem}
        }
        \@tempa
}

% Command in which colors are necessary
\newcommand{\drawcoloredarrows}[1]{
    \foreach \i  in {#1}{
        \edef\mycolor{\@nameuse{color@\i}}
        \draw[\mycolor,-stealth] (0,-\i)--(2,-\i); 
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\setcolorlist{red,cyan,blue,green}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawcoloredarrows{1,...,4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

getting:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this macro

```
\newcommand{\setcolorlist}[1]{
        \foreach \listitem [count=\i] in {#1}{
            \global\let\@tempa\@namedef{color@\i}{\listitem}
        }
        \@tempa
}
```

you're basically doing

```
\global\let\@tempa\@namedef
```

and indeed "color@1red" and so on is printed. Then `\@tempa` (which is now `\@namedef`) has to be executed, which probably can't.

With `\setcolorlist{red,green,blue}` you want to do

```
\@namedef{color@1}{red}
\@namedef{color@2}{green}
\@namedef{color@3}{blue}
```

so you want to say

```
\@namedef{color@\i}{<expansion of \listitem>}
```

but globally. Since `\@namedef{x}` expands to

```
\expandafter\def\csname x\endcsname
```

and you need to access the expansion of `\listitem`, the following will do

```
\newcommand{\setcolorlist}[1]{%
  \foreach \listitem [count=\i] in {#1}{%
     \global\@namedef{color@\i\expandafter}\expandafter{\listitem}
  }%
}
```

Alternatively, since you know that `\listitem` and `\i` expand to a string,

```
\newcommand{\setcolorlist}[1]{%
  \foreach \listitem [count=\i] in {#1}{%
     \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
       \global\noexpand\@namedef{color@\i}{\listitem}}\x
  }%
}
```

Notice that Ahmed method works too, because at each successive step `\listitem` is defined to expand to the current color name. However that method would fail if you need to do something more complicated that a simple macro equivalence.

---

#### Mandatory `expl3` solution

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setcolorlist}{ m }
 {
  \claudio_setcolorlist:n { #1 }
 }
\int_new:N \l_claudio_cycle_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \claudio_setcolorlist:n #1
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_claudio_cycle_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_claudio_cycle_int
    \cs_set:cpn { color@ \int_to_arabic:n { \l_claudio_cycle_int } } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

You can choose whether doing the assignments globally or locally (use `\cs_gset:cpn` in the former case), but this is not necessary. So this method is superior to the `\foreach` one, as it doesn't force you to do global definitions unless you need to.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. This is a good starting point not only to understand expansions, but also for `LaTeX3` because I'm planning to have a look soon at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcolorlist}[1]{%
   \foreach \listitem [count=\i] in {#1}{
      \global\expandafter\let\csname color@\i\endcsname\listitem
   }
}

% Command in which colors are necessary
\newcommand{\drawcoloredarrows}[1]{
    \foreach \i  in {#1}{
        \draw[\@nameuse{color@\i},-stealth] (0,-\i)--(2,-\i); 
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcolorlist{red,cyan,blue,green}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawcoloredarrows{1,...,4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is my preferred approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{keyreader}
\makeatletter
\krddefinekeys{claudiocolor}[claudio@col@]{%
  cmd/1/black;cmd/2/black;cmd/3/black;cmd/4/black;cmd/5/black;cmd/6/black;
}
\newcommand*\setcolorlist[1]{\krdsetkeys{claudiocolor}{#1}}
\newcommand*\usecolor[1]{\@nameuse{claudio@col@#1}}
% Command in which colors are necessary:
\newcommand*\drawcoloredarrows[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {#1}{%
    \draw[\usecolor\x,-stealth] (0,-\x)--(2,-\x);
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcolorlist{1=red,2=blue,3=cyan,4=green,5=magenta,6=purple}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawcoloredarrows{1,...,4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\setcolorlist` works perfectly, thanks. `:)` So, basically, the definition by means of `\@namedef` was not a good choice. I should really study the _expansions_...

Comment: You have a redundant `\expandafter`. :)