# Automatic generation of side branches

Tags: chemfig

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically define the atoms in a ring without manually writing each atom. For example, if I want to do this:

```
\chemfig{A*6(-A-A-A-A-A-)}
```

or this:

```
\chemfig{**6((-A)-(-A)-(-A)-(-A)-(-A)-(-A)-)}
```

[image: Enhanced ring]

I have to write `A` or `(-A)` six times. Can we maybe somehow automate this (e.g. by redefining the definition of the bond)? In ideal case, the command should look like e.g.

```
\chemfig{**6[(-A)]{------}
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Please keep in mind for the future to add always a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the command `\atom{#1}{#2}{#3}` for both versions (`\chemfig{A*6(-A-A-A-A-A-)}` and `\chemfig{**6((-A)-(-A)-(-A)-(-A)-(-A)-(-A)-)}`). The code is filled with an for loop. The versions (* and **) are handled with `ifcase`.

## **Input arguments:**

- #1: use 1 or 2 -> 1 = ring; 2 = ring/inside arc
- #2: number of elements -> for example 6
- #3: chemical element symbol ->

## Result: `\atom{1}{6}{A}` and `\atom{2}{6}{B}`

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand{\atom}[3]
{
%#1: * or ** => 1 or 2
%#2: number of elements => number
%#3: element => letter
\ifcase#1
\or%\if#1=1
\def\CZ{#3}
\def\N{#2}
\def\myarray{-}

\pgfmathparse{\N-1}
\def\lastIndex{\pgfmathresult}

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\lastIndex}
{
\edef\myarray{\myarray\CZ-}
\afterforeachdef\myarray
}
\edef\myarray{\CZ*\N(\myarray)}
\expandafter\chemfig\expandafter{\myarray}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399618/124842
\or%\if#1=2 %Version 2 with **
\def\CZ{#3}
\def\N{#2}
\def\myarray{}
\pgfmathparse{\N}
\def\lastIndex{\pgfmathresult}
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\lastIndex}
{
\edef\myarray{\myarray(-\CZ)-}
\afterforeachdef\myarray
}
\edef\myarray{**\N(\myarray)}
\expandafter\chemfig\expandafter{\myarray}
 \else 
  Wrong input number! Use 1 or 2 (argument \#1).
\fi
}

% ------------------------------------------------------------
%%%%% @Paul Gaborit:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69508/124842
\usepackage{etextools}
\makeatletter
% define a macro after current iteration
\newcommand\afteriterationdef[1]{\aftergroup@def#1}
% define a macro after foreach (and after iteration)
\newcommand\afterforeachdef[1]{\afteriterationdef{#1}\AfterGroup{\aftergroup@def#1}}
\makeatother
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\atom{1}{6}{A}

\atom{2}{6}{B}
\end{document}
```

Ref.:

@PaulGaborit:[How to define macros in a foreach loop with effects between iterations and after the loop without using global?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69508/124842)

@egreg: [Is it possible to use an macro as input argument of \chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399627/124842)

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that it could be so "sophisticated". What I had in mind is that it would maybe take use of the tikz (which is under the chemfig hood) and redefine the tikz nodes. But your approach works as well indeed. Thanks.