# Is it possible to use an macro as input argument of \chemfig?

Tags: macros, chemfig

I'm trying to replace the `code` of `\chemfig<code>` (`\chemfig{C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-)}`) with the definition of the command `\mymacroC` (`\def\mymacroC{C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-)}`). But the result isn't the same.

Does someone know why i can't use an own macro definiton to achieve the same result?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
works as expected:\\
\chemfig{C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-)}

does not work as expected:\\
\def\mymacroC{C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-)}% or also \newcommand does not work
\chemfig{\mymacroC}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Why not `\definesubmol{hexC}{C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-)}` and `\chemfig{!{hexC}}`? See section 7 in the manual.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your comment, but with `\definesubmol{hexC}{\mymacro}` i have the same problem. The problem is that i can't write `C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-)` diretly. I need `\mymacro` or something else, which get filled in a for loop. But `\chemfig{\mymacro}` does not work and i don't know why.

Comment: `\expandafter\chemfig\expandafter{\mymacro}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `\chemfig` tries doing no expansion to its main argument.

The package provides a way for defining shorthands, with

```
\definesubmol{hexC}{C*6(-C-C-C-C-C-)}
```

in the preamble and

```
\chemfig{!{hexC}}
```

in the body (see section 7 in the manual).

On the other hand, a “standard”

```
\expandafter\chemfig\expandafter{\mymacro}
```

will do (when you need no optional argument to `\chemfig`).