# Getting \let definitions from inside a group, inside a loop

Tags: loops, etoolbox, scoping

I have the following nested loop situation:

```
\begingroup
  \def\do##1{%
    \begingroup
      \def\do####1{%
         \csletcs{somemacro@##1@####1}{someothermacro@##1@####1}}%
      \dolistloop\somelista
    \endgroup}%
  \dolistloop\somelistb
\endgroup
```

where I need to have the `\csletcs` definition exist outside of the two groups but *not* globally. There is a nice trick from Martin Scharrer in a comment to this question:

[How do I get a value out of a group?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56294/how-do-i-get-a-value-out-of-a-group)

but it doesn't work in a loop like this as putting the `\endgroup`s in the inner loop really mess the next loop iterations up. Is there any way (etoolbox is ok) to get the `\csletcs` definitions out of the groups without breaking further iterations of the loops? I assume I need the groups otherwise the do loop arguments don't reference properly.

Just for completeness, here is an attempted solution using Martin Sharrer's trick:

```
\begingroup
  \def\do##1{%
    \begingroup
      \def\do####1{%
         \edef\@z{\endgroup\endgroup\csletcs{somemacro@##1@####1}{someothermacro@##1@####1}}\@z}%
      \dolistloop\somelista
    \endgroup}%
  \dolistloop\somelistb
\endgroup
```

This works for the first nested iteration and the resulting cs is defined properly outside of the groups. Unfortunately, the groups are then closed and the next iterations are a real mess.

Comment: Perhaps you could make it global within the group, access it outside as desired and then `\undef` it with one of the solutions from [How to undo a \def (i.e., Need a \undef capability)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20655/how-to-undo-a-def-i-e-need-a-undef-capability).  So then it no longer exists globally.

Comment: I thought of that but how do I make it global within the group without first `\def`ing or `\let`ing etc. outside of the inner groups? Bear in mind that I need the `\do` loop argument values `##1` and `####1` in the definitions and they are only available inside the two groups so I don't have the information to define the cs outside of the groups ...

Comment: As far as I can see, the group is used for redefining `\do` in order to process the "inner list"; you can use whatever command you want for processing a list, see `\forlistloop`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example is a little incomplete (I had to make some changes to get it to compile), but the gist of the answer is just to collect your definitions into a token list (set globally) and then expand the list after the second group (causing local definitions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\somelista{x}
\def\somelistb{y}

\texttt{\meaning\somemacro@y@x}
\def\someothermacro@y@x{a}
\begingroup
  \def\do#1{%
    \begingroup
    \def\do##1{%
      \global\toks1=\expandafter{\the\toks1 \csletcs{somemacro@#1@##1}{someothermacro@#1@##1}}}%
    \dolistloop\somelista
    \endgroup}%
  \dolistloop\somelistb
\endgroup
\the\toks1
\texttt{\meaning\somemacro@y@x}

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Gives: "undefined macro:->a" as the typeset output.

Comment: Or was I supposed to use `\toks1` for global definitions?  I forget.

Comment: Great, thanks. I had not really looked at token registers - this is a new area for me. But it works. I tried to make it neater using `\addto@hook` but this seems to give me errors but I'll look at that.

Comment: To be honest, the token register is unnecessary.  One could also use macros, for which I think a simple `\gappto` would suffice.

Comment: Ah, right, that's a good point, I can try that.

Comment: Yes, `\gappto` works nicely too. This is still the correct answer for me though - it's the subtlety that the global macro/toks can be used to define non global macros depending on where it's used that's such a nice thing to realise. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanReich Yes, it's better to use `\toks1`; I've amended it and also added a space before `\csletcs` that otherwise would be expanded, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use whatever handler you want for processing a list using `\forlistloop` instead of `\dolistloop`; so you don't need to redefine `\do` in a group not to clobber the outer loop definition: just use two different handlers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\processlistb[1]{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \forlistloop\processlista\somelista
}
\newcommand\processlista[1]{%
  \csletcs{somemacro@\temp @#1}{someothermacro@\temp @#1}%
  \csshow{somemacro@\temp @#1}%
}

\listadd\somelista{a}
\listadd\somelista{b}
\listadd\somelista{c}

\listadd\somelistb{x}
\listadd\somelistb{y}

% Just to add some mock definitions
\csdef{someothermacro@x@a}{xa}
\csdef{someothermacro@x@b}{xb}
\csdef{someothermacro@x@c}{xc}
\csdef{someothermacro@y@a}{ya}
\csdef{someothermacro@y@b}{yb}
\csdef{someothermacro@y@c}{yc}

% Do the iterations
\forlistloop\processlistb\somelistb

\stop
```

The relevant part of the log file:

```
> \somemacro@x@a=macro:
->xa.
<recently read> \somemacro@x@a

l.29 \forlistloop\processlistb\somelistb

?
> \somemacro@x@b=macro:
->xb.
<recently read> \somemacro@x@b

l.29 \forlistloop\processlistb\somelistb

?
> \somemacro@x@c=macro:
->xc.
<recently read> \somemacro@x@c

l.29 \forlistloop\processlistb\somelistb

?
> \somemacro@y@a=macro:
->ya.
<recently read> \somemacro@y@a

l.29 \forlistloop\processlistb\somelistb

?
> \somemacro@y@b=macro:
->yb.
<recently read> \somemacro@y@b

l.29 \forlistloop\processlistb\somelistb

?
> \somemacro@y@c=macro:
->yc.
<recently read> \somemacro@y@c

l.29 \forlistloop\processlistb\somelistb

?
```

Comment: I did try this before using `\dolistloop` but I have problems as the macro that contains this is embedded in a pile of stuff which also runs in loops etc. I may try it again but I have it working with `\dolistloop` at the moment