# Latex3: elegant way to forward a variable outside of the group

Tags: latex3, grouping

I want to define a macro in a group in LaTeX3 so that it stays defined after the group, but without using global variables. For now I do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{}{}{
  \str_clear_new:N \mytest
  \str_put_right:Nx \mytest {I ~ like ~}
  \str_gset_eq:NN \dummyvar \mytest
  \group_insert_after:N \str_set_eq:NN
  \group_insert_after:N \mytest
  \group_insert_after:N \dummyvar
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\def\mytest{chocolate.}
{
  \begin{test}
    I’d like mytest to be defined at the end of the group without using global variables.
  \end{test}
  \mytest
}
\mytest
\end{document}
```

It works, but it seems really dirty, like I need to introduce a global dummy var etc… I tried to do:

```
  \group_insert_after:N \str_set_eq:NN
  \group_insert_after:N \mytest
  \expandafter \group_insert_after:N \mytest
```

But funnily, the string is written backward now!! I also tried to generate a variant of `\group_insert_after:V` but it is forbidden.

Comment: I might get away with something like `\exp_args:NNNNNV \group_insert_after:N \str_set_eq:NN \group_insert_after:N \mytest \group_insert_after:N \mytest` (you'll probably have to generate `\exp_args:NNNNNV` though).

Comment: @gusbrs, thanks, so I tried, using `\exp_args_generate:n {NNNNV}`, but can’t make it work, not sure if I’m doing something stupid…Could you provide a full example by any chance?

Comment: Mhm, sorry, it was just an idea, which I can't seem to make it work either... :-(

Comment: (Off-topic, you probably don't want to call `\str_clear_new:N \mytest` inside the environment, since it may be used multiple times).

Comment: You might find this useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56294/86 It's an old question so hopefully there are more modern answers so I'll be interested in what advice you get.

Answer (score 9):

I understand that `\dummyvar` cannot work if you want to keep the meaning of more than single macro after group. But you can set a control sequence derived from the name of given control sequence:

```
\def\keepaftergroup#1{%
   \global \expandafter\let \csname x:\string#1\endcsname =#1
   \aftergroup\let
   \aftergroup#1%
   \expandafter\aftergroup \csname x:\string#1\endcsname
   
}

\def\mytest{nazdar}

{
   \def\mytest{Hello}
   \def\mysecond{Hi}
   \keepaftergroup\mytest
   \keepaftergroup\mysecond
   Text in group.%
}
After group: \mytest, \mysecond
```

Answer (score 5):

We do not currently have an 'escape from arbitrary group levels' function, largely as this is an unusual requirement. On the other hand, where you want to set a variable outside a group you control, this is quite straight-forward

```latex
\group_begin:
   % Stuff happens
   \str_set:Nn \l__mypkg_str { ... }
\exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
\str_set:Nn \l__mypkg_str \l__mypkg_str
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks but this would not work for environments right? I'm surprised, people never try to save a variable from an environment for later use?

Comment: @tobiasBora Environments are group, so usually either things are supposed to be retained insider them _or_ they are globals

Comment: Well they also have the advantage of not tempering the content, which is practical to deal with verbatim content ^^ (+ they are sometimes more visual for big content)

Answer (score 4):

The following defines a mechanism to smuggle things up one level with a single auxiliary global token.

It won't work for `toks` registers. I hope I didn't screw up on other points of the implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g__tobiasbora_smuggler_tl
\cs_new:Npn \tobiasbora_smuggle:n #1
  {
    \tl_gset:Nx \g__tobiasbora_smuggler_tl
      {
        \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \__tobiasbora_smuggle:N
        \exp_not:n { \tl_gset:Nn \g__tobiasbora_smuggler_tl }
          { \exp_not:o \g__tobiasbora_smuggler_tl }
      }
    \group_insert_after:N \g__tobiasbora_smuggler_tl
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__tobiasbora_smuggle:N #1
  {
    \token_if_macro:NTF #1
      {
        \exp_not:n { \cs_set:Npx #1 }
          { \exp_not:N \exp_not:n { \exp_not:o #1 } }
      }
      {
        \token_if_chardef:NTF #1
          { \exp_not:n { \chardef #1 } = \exp_not:V #1 \scan_stop: }
          {
            \token_if_mathchardef:NTF #1
              { \exp_not:n { \mathchardef #1 } = \exp_not:V #1 \scan_stop: }
              {
                % assume it's a register type and the following is fine
                #1 = \exp_not:V #1 \scan_stop:
              }
          }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{}{}{
  \str_set:Nn \mytest { like~ }
  \tobiasbora_smuggle:n { \mytest \mycount }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcount\mycount
\mycount=0

\begin{document}
\def\mytest{chocolate.}
{
  \begin{test}
    I’d like mytest to be defined at the end of the group without using global variables.
    \mycount=1
  \end{test}%
  \uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\mycount} % this prints "I"
  \mytest
}%
\mytest
\romannumeral\mycount % this prints nothing as it's 0 again
\end{document}
```

Comment: How funny one, should be buitin in LaTeX3!